# Secure way to pass sensitive information to iframe

Tags: javascript, security, iframe

I have to pass authentication token from my website to my iframe in a secure way. My iframe is located on the same domain as my website.

*Is it secure to pass auth token as parameter to iframe's `src` property?* I mean:

```
<iframe src={"/purse/index.html?auth_token=" + token} />
```

---

**UPDATE:** By secure I mean that no-one except current (signed in) user have a chance to access the token.

*P.S.* In your answer pls also describe the way `auth_token` could be stolen with my approach

Comment: Depends on how you define “secure”, resp. who you actually want to hide it from. The user of your site can of course simply look in the source code, or check the network requests in the browser’s dev tools, and see that you are passing that value.

Comment: Plus, HTTP referrer might be an additional concern. If your page inside the iframe embeds any external resources, the full iframe URL might get send as referrer to a remote server.

Comment: are you using any server side language?

Comment: @Pete sure:) We're using Java

Comment: @CBroe I want to hide auth token from everyone except current user that's signed into my app

Comment: You could set a server side session var on the page that holds the iframe and then check for it in the page you are showing in the iframe - as your pages are on the same server this may work and stop anyone else from just copying the source url of the iframe

Comment: @Pete I've seen next solution `$frame.on('load', () => $frame.contentWindow.init(token))`. Is it secure?

Comment: @Pete About your previous comment: I cannot get session-scope variables from within iframe, since I need token to restore session from iframe. Without token I can't ask server to return any user-related variables, right?

Comment: This is really beyond specific Javascript functions or syntax. You're sending the token to the client browser. What exactly happens there is almost irrelevant. If there are any 3rd party scripts embedded in the site, they may have access to that token, because they have access to anything else in the DOM. Otherwise, you're as secure as you can be with any other sensitive information you pass to the client.

Comment: I would have thought as it is the same user that is browsing then the session should be shared across the iframe as  it is on the same domain  - I may be wrong though.  I find the problem with doing it with js is that you can never hide your token so anyone can just look at your code and copy it

Comment: @deceze pass `auth_token` as `iframe.src` have the same security cons as keeping `auth_token` at global `var`, right? Then keeping `auth_token` at local storage and pass it into iframe as `$frame.on('load', () => $frame.contentWindow.init(token))` have the same benefits as localStorage have on global `var`

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk I recently came across with same type of situation as you were before 2 years. I am thinking to pass JWT token as part of `src`. Did you get any security issue in last couple of years which this approach?

Answer (score 4):

Technically an auth_token does not provide security, it provides identity.  Security would be provided by your encryption and authentication system, usually SSL with some form of login.  The auth_token is usually set after authentication and passed over an SSL encrypted connection back to the user.   Based on the 'src' in the provided snippet, it appears to be to the same application space - no host info that would suggest a different host.  If SSL is still being used to encrypt the connection, then there should not be a concern with anyone else 'seeing' that users auth_token.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is partially correct. Ultimately it is up to you to determine if the token is allowed to be viewed by others. In this situation, you are allowing that token to be public.

URLs are public and this includes the query parameters. So in this situation, the iframe is loaded and anyone can have access to that token. This includes, systems that log the URL, malicious JS on the page, and anyone snooping on network traffic. To securely pass the token you must include it in the signed part of the request, such as a header (and of course be using TLS or some other security mechanism).